# Correct background size for Android App

Tags: android, background

I'm creating a background image for an Android app.

The App should run on all devices so the background image will be tiled.

However I would like that the background fits exactly on a 240x400 pixels (WQVGA), 3.2'' TFT LCD (Archos32' screen size).

So I've created a backgorund image of 240x400 pixels and placed it in the drawable-ldpi folder. Then I started an emulator with WQVGA resolution and 120dpi. My background image fit exactly on the horizontal axis but it's cropped on the vertical one.

So my question is: what's the right resolution for the background image on a 240x400 ldpi device?

Answer (score 0):

If as you said your image is to be tiled then you can just create an xml to tile the image to any screensize

filename: /res/drawable/striprepeat.xml

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/stripe" 
android:tileMode="repeat" 
/>
```

and I have a stripe background image (/res/drawable/stripe.png) which has res of 22x22

Comment: Yes, my image (which is 240x400 pixels) is already tiled in that way. However it doesn't fit an emultator screen with WQVGA res.

Comment: What do you mean? A tiled image will fit any size screen. If it doesn't then perhaps there is something wrong with your layout.

Comment: The image looks bigger than the screen's size: it's cut down.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the image in all drawable folders, and use "`wrap_content`" in height and width properties. avoid specifying numbers in xml, rather use wieghts.